# TypeError when generating angular-fullstack service?

Tags: node.js, angular-fullstack

I'm receiving the following TypeError when trying to generate an angular-fullstack service.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is my terminal window:

```
Justins-MacBook-Pro-2:epbWebApp Justin$ yo angular-fullstack:service
? What module name would you like to use? epbWebAppApp.event
? Where would you like to create this service? event
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
at Object.join (path.js:1213:7)
at /Users/Justin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/generator-ng-component/service/index.js:28:21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DUH! I re-read the documentation and I simply forgot that you must specify a name for the service in the initial command.

I typed the first command as follows, and it worked!

```
yo angular-fullstack:service [NAME]
```

Then I was able to specify module name and location in the following two prompts.